# When background image is applied the header is gone in tcpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF using TCPDF. I need it to have a header which include some information and a background image. The main purpose of the background image is to act like a watermark.

The header was working just fine. However when I added a background image the header is gone.

Here is the Header function code:

```
public function Header(){
 $html = '
 <table>
 <tr>
   <td style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 8px;">PlayGround Name </td>
   <td></td> 
    <td style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 8px;">'.date('d-m-Y').'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 8px;">Page 1/1 </td> 
 </tr>

 </table>

 ';
 $this->writeHTMLCell($w = 0, $h = 0, $x = '', $y = '', $html, $border = 0, $ln = 1, $fill = 0, $reseth = true, $align = 'top', $autopadding = true);


// get the current page break margin
    $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
    // get current auto-page-break mode
    $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
    // disable auto-page-break
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
    // set bacground image
    $img_file = base_url().'assets/images/demo.jpg';

    $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
    // restore auto-page-break status
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
    // set the starting point for the page content
    $this->setPageMark();

}
```

I want both the header and the background image.
Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Reading through [manual](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#a15d65cdde4d6d9df6d1c7fdb985c0e22) says:

> [...] Background images must be always inserted before calling Multicell() or WriteHTMLCell() or WriteHTML() functions.

This means that the `Image()` should be called earlier than the `WriteHTMLCell()` function in your code. Then you should be good.

Comment: If this solved your problems, please, select this answer as "accepted". To see how the things work here, it is good to go through the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).